# How to use latitude/longitude with projection in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj, sp, rgdal

I am using the SABS dataset:
http://nces.ed.gov/surveys/sdds/sabs/

In particular, let's say I am using the "SABS_1314_High" layer. (This provides the school attendance boundaries for many US school districts.) The identifying variable is "ncessch".

I also have a list of latitude and longitude coordinates that looks like this ("sampledata.csv"):

```
num lat long
1   37.378309   -122.052739
2   37.320722   -122.020981
3   37.436397   -122.149727
```

For each row of this, I want to know the "ncessch" value of the polygon that the point belongs in.

After much trial and error (I am completely new to GIS, though not to R), I am able to read in the shapefile properly, together with its projection:

```
library(rgdal)
poly3 <- readOGR (".", "SABS_1314_High")
proj4string(poly3)
[1] "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

I can also create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` for my list of points:

```
library(sp)
locations <- read.csv("sampledata_2.csv", header = TRUE)
locations <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(locations[ , 2:3], locations)
```

At this point, it would appear that I need to use the `over` function in the `sp` package to check, for each point, which polygon it lies in, but that throws an error:

```
over(locations, poly3)
Error: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

It would therefore appear that the projections are not the same. Okay, so I tried a couple of different things:

```
library(mapproj)
locations.proj <- mapproject(locations[,2], locations[,3], projection = proj4string(poly3))
Error in min(x, na.rm = na.rm) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
```

Using a different package:

```
library(proj4)
locations.proj <- project(locations[,2:3], proj = proj4string(poly3))
Error in as.numeric(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are required to transform `sampledata` to the spatial projection of the polygons shapefile. Here is a code snippet that should help you out.

```
library(rgdal)

### polygon data -----
spy <- readOGR("/home/fdetsch/Downloads", "SABS_1314_High")

### point data -----
sampledata <- data.frame(num = 1:3,  
                         lat = c(37.378309, 37.320722, 37.436397),
                         long = c(-122.052739, -122.020981, -122.149727))

coordinates(sampledata) <- ~ long + lat
proj4string(sampledata) <- "+init=epsg:4326"

## transform to spatial projection of polygons
sampledata <- spTransform(sampledata, CRS = CRS(proj4string(spy)))

### overlay -----
spy_sub <- spy[sampledata, ]
```

The corresponding values of 'ncessch' are then to be found in `spy_sub@data`. Here is what the resulting dataset looks like (including the sample points).

```
spplot(spy_sub, "ncessch", colorkey = FALSE, scales = list(draw = TRUE),
       sp.layout = list("sp.points", sampledata, pch = 1:3, cex = 1, col = "black"))
```

[image: result]